Replacing looping and operating through a domain with numpy operations
I need to loop through a (i,j) domain and do some math on them, but the loop itself takes a very long time to run and I was wondering if there's a way to replace the for loops with vectorization calculations?
import numpy as np

# Variable Init
tole = 1e-4
residual = 1
Nx = int(1e3)
Ny = Nx
sigma = np.zeros((Nx,Ny))
R = np.zeros((Nx,Ny))

# Sample constants
a = 10
b = 3
c = 2
d = 1
w = 0.5

# Output: Sigma and residual after convergence
while residual > tole:
    for i in range(1,Nx-1):
        for j in range(1,Ny-1):
            temp = a * sigma[j, i + 1] + b * sigma[j, i - 1] + c * sigma[j + 1, i] + d * sigma[j - 1, i]

            R[j, i] = abs(sigma[j,i] - temp)
            sigma[j, i] = (1 - w) * sigma[j,i] + w * temp
    residual = np.sum(R)/(Nx*Ny)



My current numpy solution:
import numpy as np

# Variable Init
tole = 1e-4
residual = 1
Nx = int(1e3)
Ny = Nx
sigma = np.zeros((Nx,Ny))
R = np.zeros((Nx,Ny))

# Sample constants
a = 10
b = 3
c = 2
d = 1
w = 0.5

# Output: Sigma and residual after convergence
while residual > tole:
    
    temp = a * sigma[:-1, 1:] + b * sigma[1:, :-1] + c * sigma[1:, :-1] + d * sigma[:-1, 1:]
    R = sigma[:-1,:-1] - temp
    sigma[:-1,:-1] = (1 - w) * sigma[:-1,:-1] + w * temp
    residual = np.sum(R)/(Nx*Ny)


It shouldn't show in this sample since the majority has been cut out, but in the full version the residual does not change at all, which leads me to think that sigma is somehow not iterating on itself. Not quite sure where the issue is though.


In the first version, temp is based on sigma values around i,j.  That in turn changes the current sigma. That's different from the second which calculates temp for all i,j; and then tries change the whole sigma.

I'm not sure, residual = 0 and tole = 1e-4 so this while residual > tole: never iterates.

@AndrejKesely Sorry! mistype on my end. Fixed it.

@hpaulj I'm not quite sure how they're too different? Both tries to calculate temp based on sigma, whether that's incrementally or at once, and then changes the working sigma array to temp? I'm quite new to Python so not sure how the launguage fundamentally works.

For these types of tasks where you have dependent variables I recommend (here it is `sigma) to try numba:
import numba
import numpy as np


@numba.njit
def calculate(
    sigma,
    R,
    residual=1.0,
    tole=1e-4,
    a=10.0,
    b=3.0,
    c=2.0,
    d=1.0,
    w=0.5,
):
    while residual > tole:
        for i in range(1, Nx - 1):
            for j in range(1, Ny - 1):
                temp = (
                    a * sigma[j, i + 1]
                    + b * sigma[j, i - 1]
                    + c * sigma[j + 1, i]
                    + d * sigma[j - 1, i]
                )
                R[j, i] = abs(sigma[j, i] - temp)
                sigma[j, i] = (1 - w) * sigma[j, i] + w * temp
        residual = np.sum(R) / (Nx * Ny)
    return residual


# Variable Init
tole = 1e-4
residual = 1

Nx = int(1e3)
Ny = Nx

sigma = np.zeros((Nx, Ny), dtype="float32")
R = np.zeros((Nx, Ny), dtype="float32")

r = calculate(sigma=sigma, R=R, residual=residual, tole=tole)
print(r)


You can simultaneously do your additions on all the grid:
while residual > tole:
    temp = (
        a * sigma[1:-1, 2:]
        + b * sigma[1:-1, :-2]
        + c * sigma[2:, 1:-1]
        + d * sigma[:-2, 1:-1]
    )

    R[1:-1, 1:-1] = np.abs(sigma[1:-1, 1:-1] - temp)
    sigma[1:-1, 1:-1] = (1 - w) * sigma[1:-1, 1:-1] + w * temp

    residual = np.sum(R) / (Nx * Ny)

Note that the values on the border will never change, as in your example.
I did not make your code converge so I could not compare the outputs between your version and mine
